# Semisimple matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and suppose the matrix ring $M_n(R)$ is semisimple. How does one proof that $R$ is semisimple?

Comment: Well, $R$ is *Morita equivalent* to $M_n(R)$, meaning that their categories of modules are equivalent.

Comment: Is there a more direct way to see this using Artin-Wedderburn?

Comment: That's if you want to show that the semisimplicity of $R$ implies the semisimplicity of $M_n(R)$.

Comment: @J.Bosser Sorry, yes, of course.  The alternative to what I'm thinking of that proves that is too close to Berci's comment to mention as an alternative.